# You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function error - solution?

Tags: vue.js

I am getting error "You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function." What should I do?

I have tried making the arrays a data value. Also, I have tried using a *for* loop. It seems like it's isolated in the first method.

```typescript
data() {
  return {
      activeTab: 0,
      uniqueLobs: []
    }
},
methods: {
    addDollarSymbol(val){
        var newVal = "$" + val;
        return newVal.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, ''); // Trims white space
    },
    removeDuplicateLOB(lineOfBusiness) {
        // Removes duplicate LOBs for tabs
        let incomingLobs = [];
        lineOfBusiness.forEach((business) => {
        incomingLobs.push(business.line_of_business.name);
        });
        this.uniqueLobs = [...new Set(incomingLobs)];
        return this.uniqueLobs;
    },
    showSpecificLobData(activeTab){
        //compares tab LOB to all incoming card data and shows only the LOB data for that specific tab
        let activeTabData = [];
        this.product_rate_card.forEach((product) => {
            if (product.line_of_business.name == this.uniqueLobs[activeTab] ) {
                activeTabData.push(product);
            }
        });
        return activeTabData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your all code inside `script` tag

Answer (score 0):

The 'loop' in this case refers to an infinite recursion rather than a `for` loop.

That warning is logged here:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/ff911c9ffef16c591b25df05cb2322ee737d13e0/src/core/observer/scheduler.js#L104

It may not be immediately obvious what most of that is doing but the key part of the code is the line `if (circular[id] > MAX_UPDATE_COUNT) {`, which is checking whether a particular watcher has been triggered more than 100 times.

When reactive data changes it will cause any components that depend on that data to be re-rendered. If the rendering process changes that same data then rendering will be triggered again. If the data never stabilizes then this will continue forever.

Here's a simple example of a component that triggers that warning:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        {{ getNextCount() }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            count: 1
        }
    },

    methods: {
        getNextCount () {
            this.count++

            return this.count
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The template has a dependency on `count` but by calling `getNextCount` it will also change the value of `count`. When that value changes the component will be re-added to the rendering queue because a dependency has changed. It can never break out of this cycle because the value keeps changing.

I can't say for sure what is causing this problem in your component as you haven't posted enough code. However, it could be something like the line `this.uniqueLobs = ...`, assuming that is being called during rendering. In general I would suggest avoiding changing anything on `this` during the rendering phase. Rendering should be read-only. Generally you'd use computed properties for any derived data that you want to keep around.

Comment: I added more to the code above. Turns out, removing the uniqueLobs set within the data fixed the issue.

Comment: @MohammedFahad The extra code you've posted doesn't really clarify anything, the key missing piece is the template or render function. Removing uniqueLobs from within the data will make it non-reactive, so no dependency will be created. This may make the warning go away but it is subverting the reactivity system. Unless you fully understand what is going on here it'll likely come back to bite you.

Comment: Hmmmm so I've got tabs that are showing different data based on the LOB. And after I removed uniqueLob = [], the infinite loop error went away and the clicking on each tab gives me the desired values/cards for each tab

Answer (score 0):

Most times it’s as a result of how you're passing props to another component.

If it’s Vue.js 2, try using `v-on:[variable-name]`.