# Using counter flag in v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I want to use a counter flag in v-for inside another v-for loop for counting total run of inside loop.
Here is my template:

```
<a :href="'#/product/'+list.id" :id="ikeyCounter" v-for="item,ikey in section.list" class="movie item fcosuable">
 {{ ikeyCounterPlus() }}
  <div class="verticalImage">
   <div class="loader hideloading"></div>
   <img :src="item.thumb" alt="">
</div>
</a>
```

```
data() {
 return {
  loading: true,
  status: null,
  list: [],
  sections: null,
  ikeyCounter: 3
 }
},
```

And method:

```
ikeyCounterPlus() {
 this.ikeyCounter++;
},
```

but I'm getting wrong result on ikeyCounter variable. Id of a tag started from "15003" to "15150", if I don't call ikeyCounterPlus() inside v-for tag, for loop will run correctly (150 run)

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56302807. Are you not seeing an error message about an infinite recursion?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count your objects, then just count your data. No need to involve DOM.

`section.list` is an array, so `section.list.length` should give you desired count.

Also, as mentioned in the answer before, use some unique property of `item` (for example some sort of id) as the value for `:key` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it like this, Vue.js is reactive framework and you should learn a little bit before asking these kind of questions - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Use your `key` as `id` instead